# Slow rendering content with image from database to text editor

Tags: laravel, tinymce

After inserting content(text and image) inside the the text editor and saving it , the page becomes very slow when loading or rendering the content with image back inside the editor. The browser sometime crashes.

The page renders very fast when I upload PNG image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7aVEyNA31-8dcLjWXEyMv91nQ1SLC4B/view?usp=sharing

DATABASE TABEL FIELD DATA TYPE => LONGTEXT

I was expecting the page to load fast when rendering the image in the text editor.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.TinyMce',
    // plugins: 'image code',
    plugins: [
            'a11ychecker', 'advcode', 'advlist', 'anchor', 'autolink',  'fullscreen', 'help',
            'image', 'editimage',  'lists', 'link', 'media', 'powerpaste', 'preview',
            'searchreplace', 'table', 'tinymcespellchecker', 'visualblocks', 'wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'insertfile a11ycheck undo redo | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | template codesample | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image | fontsize',
    //toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    /* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
    image_title: true,
    /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
    automatic_uploads: true,
    /*
      URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
      images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
      here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
    */
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    /* and here's our custom image picker*/
    file_picker_callback: (cb, value, meta) => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png');
  
      input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
  
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          /*
            Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
            registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
            necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
          */
          const id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
          const blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
          const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
          const blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
          blobCache.add(blobInfo);
  
          /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
          cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
  
      input.click();
    },
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px }'
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYXan.png)